# Disk and Network Usage According to Resource Monitor

Tags: windows, resource-monitor

I notice when I open up resource monitor, the graphical portion of the utility shows constant spikes reaching the top of the graph for both network and disk usage at times. You would think my system would be screeching to an abrupt halt by looking at the representation but it does not. I also notice that it's measuring a very small percentage of the total bandwidth for each given connection.

For example, instead of 100 Mbps for my network utilization it shows only kbps and rather than  representing my disk transfer rates in MB/s it shows it in kB/s.

With this its hard to tell whether my system is in fact reaching its limit.

Is this normal?

[image: Disk Usage]

Comment: What are the actual values? Perhaps a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Edited original post with pic

Comment: explain which issue you have, currently I have no idea what you want.

Comment: There isn't a problem. I'm confused as to why they would graph the charts in kb/s when the full network and disk bandwidth is in the MB/s

Answer (score 0):

The reason this shows in kb instead of MB isn't because you're hitting your limit - its because you are only using up to 100KB per sec, so it only graphs that high and will adjust dynamically as you use the drives/network more.  Imaging how little that line would move if you had an SSD capable of hundreds of MB per second!  The graph adjusts based on the usage intensity - its nothing to be concerned about.